# TOR is unstable on Linux (Debian). Address already in use

Tags: configuration

I installed TOR on the server with the command:

```
apt-get install tor
```

I corrected the configuration file and it looks like this (/etc/tor/torrc):

```
## Configuration file for a typical Tor user
## Last updated 9 October 2013 for Tor 0.2.5.2-alpha.
## (may or may not work for much older or much newer versions of Tor.)
##
## Lines that begin with "## " try to explain what's going on. Lines
## that begin with just "#" are disabled commands: you can enable them
## by removing the "#" symbol.
##
## See 'man tor', or https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html,
## for more options you can use in this file.
##
## Tor will look for this file in various places based on your platform:
## https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#torrc

## Tor opens a socks proxy on port 9050 by default -- even if you don't
## configure one below. Set "SocksPort 0" if you plan to run Tor only
## as a relay, and not make any local application connections yourself.
#SocksPort 9050 # Default: Bind to localhost:9050 for local connections.
#SocksPort 192.168.0.1:9100 # Bind to this address:port too.
SocksPort 9052
SocksPort 9053
SocksPort 9054
SocksPort 9055
SocksPort 9056
SocksPort 9057
SocksPort 9058
SocksPort 9059
SocksPort 9060
SocksPort 9061
SocksPort 9062
SocksPort 9063
SocksPort 9064
SocksPort 9065
SocksPort 9066
SocksPort 9067
SocksPort 9068
SocksPort 9069
SocksPort 9070
SocksPort 9071
SocksPort 9072
SocksPort 9073
SocksPort 9074
SocksPort 9075
SocksPort 9076
SocksPort 9077
SocksPort 9078
SocksPort 9079
SocksPort 9080
SocksPort 9081
SocksPort 9082
SocksPort 9083
SocksPort 9084
SocksPort 9085
SocksPort 9086
SocksPort 9087
SocksPort 9088
SocksPort 9089
SocksPort 9090
SocksPort 9091
SocksPort 9092
SocksPort 9093
SocksPort 9094
SocksPort 9095
SocksPort 9096
SocksPort 9097
SocksPort 9098
SocksPort 9099
SocksPort 9100
SocksPort 9101
SocksPort 9102
SocksPort 9103
SocksPort 9104
SocksPort 9105
SocksPort 9106
SocksPort 9107
SocksPort 9108
SocksPort 9109
SocksPort 9110
SocksPort 9111
SocksPort 9112
SocksPort 9113
SocksPort 9114
SocksPort 9115
SocksPort 9116
SocksPort 9117
SocksPort 9118
SocksPort 9119
SocksPort 9120
SocksPort 9121
SocksPort 9122
SocksPort 9123
SocksPort 9124
SocksPort 9125
SocksPort 9126
SocksPort 9127
SocksPort 9128
SocksPort 9129
SocksPort 9130
SocksPort 9131
SocksPort 9132
SocksPort 9133
SocksPort 9134
SocksPort 9135
SocksPort 9136
SocksPort 9137
SocksPort 9138
SocksPort 9139
SocksPort 9140
SocksPort 9141
SocksPort 9142
SocksPort 9143
SocksPort 9144
SocksPort 9145
SocksPort 9146
SocksPort 9147
SocksPort 9148
SocksPort 9149
SocksPort 9150
SocksPort 9151
SocksPort 9152
SocksPort 9153
SocksPort 9154
SocksPort 9155
SocksPort 9156
SocksPort 9157
SocksPort 9158
SocksPort 9159
SocksPort 9160
SocksPort 9161
SocksPort 9162
SocksPort 9163
SocksPort 9164
SocksPort 9165
SocksPort 9166
SocksPort 9167
SocksPort 9168
SocksPort 9169
SocksPort 9170
SocksPort 9171
SocksPort 9172
SocksPort 9173
SocksPort 9174
SocksPort 9175
SocksPort 9176
SocksPort 9177
SocksPort 9178
SocksPort 9179
SocksPort 9180
SocksPort 9181
SocksPort 9182
SocksPort 9183
SocksPort 9184
SocksPort 9185
SocksPort 9186
SocksPort 9187
SocksPort 9188
SocksPort 9189
SocksPort 9190
SocksPort 9191
SocksPort 9192
SocksPort 9193
SocksPort 9194
SocksPort 9195
SocksPort 9196
SocksPort 9197
SocksPort 9198
SocksPort 9199
SocksPort 9200


## Entry policies to allow/deny SOCKS requests based on IP address.
## First entry that matches wins. If no SocksPolicy is set, we accept
## all (and only) requests that reach a SocksPort. Untrusted users who
## can access your SocksPort may be able to learn about the connections
## you make.
#SocksPolicy accept 192.168.0.0/16
#SocksPolicy reject *

## Logs go to stdout at level "notice" unless redirected by something
## else, like one of the below lines. You can have as many Log lines as
## you want.
##
## We advise using "notice" in most cases, since anything more verbose
## may provide sensitive information to an attacker who obtains the logs.
##
## Send all messages of level 'notice' or higher to /var/log/tor/notices.log
#Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
## Send every possible message to /var/log/tor/debug.log
#Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
## Use the system log instead of Tor's logfiles
#Log notice syslog
## To send all messages to stderr:
#Log debug stderr

## Uncomment this to start the process in the background... or use
## --runasdaemon 1 on the command line. This is ignored on Windows;
## see the FAQ entry if you want Tor to run as an NT service.
#RunAsDaemon 1

## The directory for keeping all the keys/etc. By default, we store
## things in $HOME/.tor on Unix, and in Application Data\tor on Windows.
#DataDirectory /var/lib/tor

## The port on which Tor will listen for local connections from Tor
## controller applications, as documented in control-spec.txt.
#ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
#HashedControlPassword 16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
#CookieAuthentication 1

############### This section is just for location-hidden services ###

## Once you have configured a hidden service, you can look at the
## contents of the file ".../hidden_service/hostname" for the address
## to tell people.
##
## HiddenServicePort x y:z says to redirect requests on port x to the
## address y:z.

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
#HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22

################ This section is just for relays #####################
#
## See https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay for details.

## Required: what port to advertise for incoming Tor connections.
#ORPort 9001
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## ORPort (e.g. to advertise 443 but bind to 9090), you can do it as
## follows.  You'll need to do ipchains or other port forwarding
## yourself to make this work.
#ORPort 443 NoListen
#ORPort 127.0.0.1:9090 NoAdvertise

## The IP address or full DNS name for incoming connections to your
## relay. Leave commented out and Tor will guess.
#Address noname.example.com

## If you have multiple network interfaces, you can specify one for
## outgoing traffic to use.
# OutboundBindAddress 10.0.0.5

## A handle for your relay, so people don't have to refer to it by key.
#Nickname ididnteditheconfig

## Define these to limit how much relayed traffic you will allow. Your
## own traffic is still unthrottled. Note that RelayBandwidthRate must
## be at least 20 KB.
## Note that units for these config options are bytes per second, not bits
## per second, and that prefixes are binary prefixes, i.e. 2^10, 2^20, etc.
#RelayBandwidthRate 100 KB  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)
#RelayBandwidthBurst 200 KB # But allow bursts up to 200KB/s (1600Kbps)

## Use these to restrict the maximum traffic per day, week, or month.
## Note that this threshold applies separately to sent and received bytes,
## not to their sum: setting "4 GB" may allow up to 8 GB total before
## hibernating.
##
## Set a maximum of 4 gigabytes each way per period.
#AccountingMax 4 GB
## Each period starts daily at midnight (AccountingMax is per day)
#AccountingStart day 00:00
## Each period starts on the 3rd of the month at 15:00 (AccountingMax
## is per month)
#AccountingStart month 3 15:00

## Administrative contact information for this relay or bridge. This line
## can be used to contact you if your relay or bridge is misconfigured or
## something else goes wrong. Note that we archive and publish all
## descriptors containing these lines and that Google indexes them, so
## spammers might also collect them. You may want to obscure the fact that
## it's an email address and/or generate a new address for this purpose.
#ContactInfo Random Person <nobody AT example dot com>
## You might also include your PGP or GPG fingerprint if you have one:
#ContactInfo 0xFFFFFFFF Random Person <nobody AT example dot com>

## Uncomment this to mirror directory information for others. Please do
## if you have enough bandwidth.
#DirPort 9030 # what port to advertise for directory connections
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## DirPort (e.g. to advertise 80 but bind to 9091), you can do it as
## follows.  below too. You'll need to do ipchains or other port
## forwarding yourself to make this work.
#DirPort 80 NoListen
#DirPort 127.0.0.1:9091 NoAdvertise
## Uncomment to return an arbitrary blob of html on your DirPort. Now you
## can explain what Tor is if anybody wonders why your IP address is
## contacting them. See contrib/tor-exit-notice.html in Tor's source
## distribution for a sample.
#DirPortFrontPage /etc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html

## Uncomment this if you run more than one Tor relay, and add the identity
## key fingerprint of each Tor relay you control, even if they're on
## different networks. You declare it here so Tor clients can avoid
## using more than one of your relays in a single circuit. See
## https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#MultipleRelays
## However, you should never include a bridge's fingerprint here, as it would
## break its concealability and potentionally reveal its IP/TCP address.
#MyFamily $keyid,$keyid,...

## A comma-separated list of exit policies. They're considered first
## to last, and the first match wins. If you want to _replace_
## the default exit policy, end this with either a reject *:* or an
## accept *:*. Otherwise, you're _augmenting_ (prepending to) the
## default exit policy. Leave commented to just use the default, which is
## described in the man page or at
## https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html
##
## Look at https://www.torproject.org/faq-abuse.html#TypicalAbuses
## for issues you might encounter if you use the default exit policy.
##
## If certain IPs and ports are blocked externally, e.g. by your firewall,
## you should update your exit policy to reflect this -- otherwise Tor
## users will be told that those destinations are down.
##
## For security, by default Tor rejects connections to private (local)
## networks, including to your public IP address. See the man page entry
## for ExitPolicyRejectPrivate if you want to allow "exit enclaving".
##
#ExitPolicy accept *:6660-6667,reject *:* # allow irc ports but no more
#ExitPolicy accept *:119 # accept nntp as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed

## Bridge relays (or "bridges") are Tor relays that aren't listed in the
## main directory. Since there is no complete public list of them, even an
## ISP that filters connections to all the known Tor relays probably
## won't be able to block all the bridges. Also, websites won't treat you
## differently because they won't know you're running Tor. If you can
## be a real relay, please do; but if not, be a bridge!
#BridgeRelay 1
## By default, Tor will advertise your bridge to users through various
## mechanisms like https://bridges.torproject.org/. If you want to run
## a private bridge, for example because you'll give out your bridge
## address manually to your friends, uncomment this line:
#PublishServerDescriptor 0

UseEntryGuards 0
EnforceDistinctSubnets 0
```

I connect to different ports:

```
 127.0.0.1:9052
 127.0.0.1:9053
 127.0.0.1:9054
```

And in random cases, connections stop working for unknown reasons. I have been struggling with the problem for several days and nothing helps me... I often notice errors like this in the logs:

```
Mar 06 03:33:38.367 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9052
Mar 06 03:33:38.367 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9052: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Mar 06 03:33:38.367 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9053
Mar 06 03:33:38.367 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9053: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Mar 06 03:33:38.367 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9054
Mar 06 03:33:38.367 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9054: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Mar 06 03:47:33.026 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Mar 06 03:47:33.026 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

The error also appears with respect to other ports that are not even used.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You already have a tor instance running (use `pgrep -a ^tor\$` to see it). Are you trying to run tor in a terminal? If so that's probably the issue. Tor installed through apt runs as a systemd service. Also why are you using so many socks ports?

Comment: @Steve Even when I use a single port, TOR still works a couple of times and then writes an error about employment. How to install it correctly so that this does not happen?

Comment: "Are you trying to run tor in a terminal? If so that's probably the issue."

Comment: @Steve, Yes, I run tor in the terminal with the `service tor start` command. How can I run it without a terminal?